# hide popup by clicking outside of it

Tags: javascript, css, popup, event-propagation

I read this article saying a popular way to close popups by clicking anywhere outside of the popup is a bad practice
https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

He gives an alternative solution in the article

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
if (!$(event.target).closest('#menucontainer').length) {
// Hide the menus.
}
});
```

Explanation of the above code: "The above handler listens for clicks on the document and checks to see if the event target is #menucontainer or has #menucontainer as a parent. If it doesn't, you know the click originated from outside of #menucontainer, and thus you can hide the menus if they're visible."

I don't use jQuery so am trying to implement something similar in vanilla.js.

One thing I tried is to stop pointer events with CSS, but there might be things inside the inner-popup, like a button, that I do want to be clickable

If it confuses matters - My popup is a black overlay with a lowered opacity with then another div inside to be the actual popup.

I tried this but it didn't work - I'm attaching the listener only after showing the popup:

```
function showPopup(popup) {
popup.style.display = "flex";
popup.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
if (!event.currentTarget.contains(target)) {
    closePopup(event.currentTarget);
}
})
```

EDIT: this works

```
function clickOutsidePopup(e, popup) {
console.log(e.target)
if (e.target.querySelector(".inner")) {
closePopup(popup);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont stop the pointer events, write a function that works instead, something like this :

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var el = e.target.closest('#menucontainer');
    if (el) {
        // click inside the popup
    } else {
        // click outside the popup
    }
});
```

Remember to remove the event handler when the popup is closed, otherwise you'll have multiple event handlers cancelling each other out.

Note that [`element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) need a polyfill to work in IE.

Comment: @Ollie_W - if `event.target` is undefined you're doing something seriously wrong. This should work just fine -> **https://jsfiddle.net/4kd7c97b/**

Comment: Closest is not supported by IE

Comment: @adeneo excellent! can you explain me why are you using setTimeOut?

Comment: @Santiago - without a time set, it's just used to "defer" something to a later time. I'm guessing I discovered an issue with rebinding the event handler at the same time as it was removed or something like that, so I just deferred it with a timeout to solve the issue in the demo I posted

Answer (score 1):

Approach a simpler way:

Create an overlay which covers the whole body (positition absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 2). Attach an onclick event which triggers the **modal.close()**;

Put your modal over that overlay. When the overlay is clicked, just remove it and close the modal. (position: absolute; z-index: 3);

Comment: This was basically the very first thing I tried. I'm already using a div that cover the whole body. Putting an event listener on the outer div also closes the popup when you click inside the popup.